# .htaccess Wildcard Redirect with Root Exception

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, wildcard

I need to redirect entire website to new site with an exception, the root (index) should redirect to /page on new site:

```
http://www.oldsite.com/ > http://www.newsite.com/page
```

There are examples with folder exception, but none with root exception, I'm afraid my tries would cause redirect loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In htaccess, you match a request for the current directory as an empty string:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.newsite.com/page [L,R]
RewriteRule .+ http://www.newsite.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```